# mysql postcode search

Tags: php, mysql

Evening All.

I have a mysql database for a property website. There is a search form where people can enter a location or postcode in the same field.

Part of the SQL is

```
PostCode LIKE '$Loc%
```

Put my problem is some people enter a post code like this : "l236yt" and some with a space like this "l23 6yt".

The database contains the postcodes with the space in them so how can make it work with or without the space ??

Any help will be greatly appreciated

thanks baz

Comment: You could remove the space from the input value using PHP

Comment: @Pekka웃 Or using MySQL.

Comment: @njk I would do this on application level, in case other characters come up that need filtering too. In mySQL, this is going to look awkward quickly

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the values in your database are without space, just sanitize the user value to a value without space:

```
$val = str_replace(' ', '', $val);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the string into an array of characters, and search for spaces, if you don't find any, you can then proceed to insert a space (the space will always be after the third character in a 6 character postcode, and after the fourth character in a 7 character postcode, so you can use regex to do this quite simply. I believe there are also postcodes which are 5 characters long, and these will be like A1 1AA, so after the second character you'll find the space.

I can't help with precise code due to my lack of knowledge of the language, but good luck!

Comment: To other posters, note that he says the postcodes are collected with the space!

Answer (score 0):

Expects a valid postcode as input (with or without spaces), and breaks it down into constituent parts as well as returning it neatly formatted with a space in the appropriate place

```
function parsePostcode($postcode) {
    $postcode = preg_replace('/\s*/','',strtoupper($postcode));

    $sector = substr($postcode,0,-2);
    $outcode = $district = substr($sector,0,-1);

    list($area) = sscanf($district,'%[A-Z]');
    $incode = substr($postcode,-3);

    return array(
        'postcode'  => $postcode,
        'formatted' => $outcode.' '.$incode,
        'area'      => $area,
        'district'  => $district,
        'sector'    => $sector,
        'outcode'   => $outcode,
        'incode'    => $incode,
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first priority is to remove the LIKE condition from your query. Using LIKE conditions forces MySQL to evaluate every row in your table and is very inefficient. Try to avoid using a LIKE unless absolutely necessary. In order to change this part of your query, you will need to replace it with:

```
PostCode = "$Loc"
```

This presents you with two options:

1) sanitise your input. Postcodes follow a well known format so it is possible to convert the value that someone enters into something you expect. You can then search on. As $Loc would match exactly what you have in the database, it would be very fast to find in your database (provided you have indexed the field of course!).

2) overload the database with multiple values to represent the same postcode. This would mean that you would put both "l236yt" and "l23 6yt" in the database and handle them as if they are different values. This also helps when you want to search on just the first part of the postcode, such as "l23", but would only work if you have a one-to-many relationship between postcodes and locations.